# How to Handle Green Key (Call Button) event in Symbian C++

Tags: c++, symbian

I want to handle the Green Key Event in Symbian. I have handled Red Key(End Button) with the help of KAknUidValueEndKeyCloseEvent. Can you suggest me what is the name of the event of Green Key. Here is the necessary code.

```
void CMobileDialerAppUi::HandleWsEventL(const TWsEvent &aEvent, CCoeControl *aDestination)
{
switch (aEvent.Type()) 

{
    case KAknUidValueEndKeyCloseEvent:
          {

                       TUid KMyAppUid = { 0x20070DF6 };
                       TApaTaskList tasklist(CCoeEnv::Static()->WsSession());
                       TApaTask task = tasklist.FindApp(KMyAppUid);
                       if(task.Exists())
                       {
                             task.BringToForeground();
                       }
                       symbian_ua_endcall();
          break;
          }

    default:

        CAknAppUi::HandleWsEventL(aEvent, aDestination);
    break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on your container override method OfferKeyEventL

```
TKeyResponse CMobileDialerContainer::OfferKeyEventL(const TKeyEvent &aKeyEvent, TEventCode aType)
{
 if (EStdKeyDevice0==aKeyEvent.iScanCode){
if (aType == EEventKeyUp) {
                    //a green key has press
                return EKeyWasConsumed;
  }
 }
 return EKeyWasConsumed;
}
```